# Why is this program giving runtime error?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a function thats reads a character string from the stdin and stores it in a character vector and also stores the position of the special character -(@) in an integer vector. It is given that the input will consist only of lowercase alphabets and the special character i.e '@'. Both the character and integer vectors are global. I can't figure out why I am getting runtime error. Here is my code:-

```
vector<int> v;
vector<char> s;

inline int input()                //called in main when we have to read input
{
    char p=getchar();
    register int i=0;
    while((p>='a'&&p<='z')||(p=='@'))  
    {
        s.push_back(p);
        if (p=='@')
        {
            v.push_back(i);
        }
        p=getchar();
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty impossible to help without knowing what runtime error you're getting.

Comment: Just curious, have you cleaned up your *compile* time errors yet?

Comment: @pinkpanther, that was a typo, I definitely have the closing quote in my code

Comment: Then please update the question with your error.

Answer (score 1):

**while((p>='a'&&p<='z')||(p=='@))**

You don't have '@'

Comment: Maybe the OP doesn't understand the difference between runtime and compile time

Comment: @kenyanke, I do have the closing quote in my program, if it wasn't there then it would have been a case of compile time error and not runtime error.

Comment: Looking back on this, you edited your question to include the quote, don't know whether you fixed it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you put the nature of the error that you get at run-time. It would also help if you gave examples of inputs that cause this error.

A few observations, which may give you some pointers to the cause of the error:

- Your vectors are global variables. It would be much better if you passed them into the function and do not store them at global scope. This will allow you to much better track where they are being accessed and changed which will make your code much more maintainable.
- Neither vector gets cleared at the start of the function so will continue to build up through subsequent calls. This may or may not be what you want to do.
- The function will terminate early if you do not either type a lowercase letter or '@'. This looks deliberate, but of course any punctuation, capitals, numbers, or spaces will cause early termination.
- You always return 0 from the function. If the function is not written to return a value it should be declared as void.

I would also remove your use of inline and register which are unlikely to give you anything of an appreciable speed increase.